# Why ADF Monitoring does not show the status of the last activity ran by pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an overall design like this picture below. When the `Condition` is `FALSE`  it correctly goes to the `False` part, runs the `FAIL ACTIVITY` I have in there and correctly takes the `"fail route"`  of the `IF activity` and correctly and successfully also sets the value of the `variable` to **NO**.  So far all good and what I expected.
**However** when I go to `Monitor` the pipeline , it shows a `FAIL`  .  My expectation is that it should show a `SUCCESS` because the last activity that `pipeline` ran was that `Set Variable` and it was successful.  So why it shows `Fail` in the monitoring section ? And also how can I get it to show `success` ?
[image]

Comment: It shows a FAIL because you told it to FAIL. That's what the FAIL activity does. It continues the pipeline because you gave it an operation to do on Failure - if you do not want the pipeline to report as a failure, delete the FAIL activity, but keep your on-error activity path.

Comment: @JoelCochran exactly. What I really want is to keep it follow the "failure activity path" without actually reporting as failure, that's why I thought I add the FAIL so it gets forced to follow the fail path.  So is there a way to tell it to follow the fail path without actually reporting as a fail ?

Comment: I see what you are after now - I think the only way to accomplish this is to embed the subsequent activities inside the IF False condition. The on-error pathway is meant for handling activity failures, not logical ones.

Comment: @JoelCochran yep, I couldn't do that because I have more "IF" in my pipeline and nested if not possible in ADF yet.  I did a quick test, I might be able to use the THIRD approach here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling

Comment: There are certainly other logical options. Secondary (child) pipelines come in handy for those scenarios where you can't nest logic.

Comment: The TRY-CATCH pattern in that article looks interesting, I have not done that before. It appears it would handle your scenario - too bad it isn't implemented as an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the if activity failed because the inner activity failed, and you handled it by using a set variable on failure of it.

But the reason for the pipeline failure is the **Fail activity**. In false activities, the Fail activity will give a failure and you didn't handle it.

[image]

[image]

A pipeline fails when the last(leaf) activities fail and here, the **Fail activity is a leaf activity**.

To solve this, you can embed the failure activities in False activities but as you have more if activities, this won't work.

The following can be a workaround for this scenario but this method is quite complex if there are more if activities in your pipeline.

Use the **Do If Skip Else block** from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling#do-if-skip-else-block)  inside the False activities.

As nested if not supported in ADF, use the set variable as if like below.

[image]

```
@if(<your condition>,'Yes',1)
```

Here, I am using the Success and failure of the set variable activity as True and false of if.

If your condition is `true`, then it will set `'Yes'` string value to the string type variable `samp` and if it is `false`, it will set the `1` integer value to `samp` which will generate the error.

First use an if activity and inside the False activities use this logic as nested if.

This won't fail the pipeline on the failure flow.

**NOTE**: If you have lot if activities, the above method may get complex, so it's better to use child pipelines in that case as suggested in comments.